# How can I call a class which will get the name of the class which is being invoked?

Tags: java, android, class, get

I have multiple classes here and I need to know which class is being invoked. From searching I got an idea of how I might do this which suggests I do this:

```
StackTraceElement[] stElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
for (int i=1; i<stElements.length; i++) {
    StackTraceElement ste = stElements[i];
    String className = ste.getClassName();
}
```

This gets me the class names but the problem is where do I should write this code so that I can get the name of the class which is being executed all the time in my app.

Comment: Is it that you want to be able to call this code from anywhere inside your app? Or is it that there is a Thread that is always running and you want the name of that class?

Comment: Thread that is always running and I have to know the name of that class

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following line after `ste.getClassName()` to see what the classname is:

```
System.out.println(className);
```

Comment: Maybe format this a little better and add the comment as narrative. Short answers tend to get deleted.